# android application with two database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Am making an app, which contains a database in the assets folder, say the database as db1. When I open the app, am again creating a db using the **API'S**. Both the db names are similar.

When copying the db I see that the db1 created using api`s is getting over written by db1 in assets. Here I have a solution that first to copy the db from assets then followed by open the same in java.
In assets folder db it contains tables namely **A**,**B**,**C** and the db created using code am making tables **A**,**B**,**C**,**D**,**E**,**F**.

Now what I want is:

When I give an upgrade for the app, I cannot blindly copy the database in the assets will overwrite all the existing data in the **db1**( All tables ). I want to know can I copy the database with some other name say **db2**. Then open and copy all the tables in **db2** and overwrite those tables in **db1** with the newly copied tables; i,e tables **A**,**B**,**C** tables in **db1** has to be replaced with with the tables in **db2**.

I want know if it is possible or not? If possible some give me some samples are references.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the app doesn't force the database to be upgraded. So unless you actually change the DB's version number, that you pass to the constructor of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, the old database won't change.

If you do change the DB's version number because you have changed the database schema, then you have to override the `onUpgrade` method, copy the necessary information from the existing DB to some temporary location (or memory), copy the DB file from assets and insert the data back.